# what happend when cout name of function whithout ( )?

Tags: function, c++17

```cpp
int res(int n)
{
    return 55;
}

int main(){
  cout<< res;  

  return 0;
}
```

I expected it to produce an error, but it printed 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refer to a function by its name alone, you get a pointer to that function.

`operator<<` does not have an overload that accepts any *arbitrary* function pointer.  It has an overload that accepts a `void*` pointer (which a function pointer is not implicitly convertible to), and overloads which accept pointers to functions that operate on output streams (which your function does not).

However, `operator<<` does have an overload that accepts a `bool`, and there is an implicit conversion defined from a function pointer to a boolean.  So, you end up with a boolean value of `true` (which gets printed as an integer `1` unless you use the [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) I/O manipulator) because the function pointer is not null.